# How to return status 4x in nginx for the URL query paramaters that are not valid

Tags: nginx

What is the way in the nginx conf file to return the status 4x for the URL that contains the invalid query parameters at the endpoint

basically i want https:/// to be accepted
anything with ?

like https:///?anticsrf the URL with ? need to be rejected.

is there a way to do that in nginx conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'll take a guess that you want to deny any requests with any URL arguments. The `$is_args` variable can be used there, so:

```
if ($is_args) {
    return 403;
}
```

This will deny requests like `/?foo=...`.